# Java8 Lambda function - adding new parameter

Tags: function, lambda, java-8

I have following code :

```
categoryList = Prices.stream()
               .filter(price -> price.getPrice() != null)
               .map(this::createCategory)
               .filter(Objects::nonNull)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And the method looks like :

```
private Category createCategory(PriceCategory price) {
        Category category = new Category();
        category.setId(price.getId());
        return category;
    }
```

I want to add a new parameter to the method createCategory - like `createCategory(PriceCategory price, response)`  But I don't have idea about setting this new parameter in the lambda function. Can anyone please help in this

Comment: You are using a method reference. Just change it to a lambda expression and the problem disappears (hint: a lambda expression is what you are using in the preceding `filter` step).

Comment: Possible but you need to define first where `response`s values will come from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can't you simply create a lambda instead?

```
.map(x -> createCategory(x, response))
```

Comment: Only in the case `response` value is defined in the closure.